# Django DRF - Is it possible to have a pre-defined form in the browsable API using function-based views?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an API built with Django DRF. I'm using function based views and I was wondering if it's possible to add a defined form (based on the model serializer) for the browsable API?

I want to turn this (the browsable API I get with function based views):
[image]

Into this (what I get with class based views):
[image]

Comment: If the class based views give you what you want then why not use them?

Comment: @IainShelvington personally I prefer function based views and I don't want to migrate.

Comment: Django and it's ecosystem have been migrating away from function based views for a long time. Not embracing this will probably hurt your project in the long run as more and more packages use/expect class based views

Comment: why dont't you use  one of the packages for providing API documentation  like swagger ui or drf-yasg